# Text not zoom? Oof

Tags: html

Here’s a link to the code that I’m testing.
How would I make the text not change size when you zoom in. I want it to stay proportional to the zoom of everything else.

https://jsfiddle.net/sbakj4x0/

```
<html>
   <h3>oof</h3>
</html>
```

Just had to put this code here for the auto requirements

Answer (score 0):

try `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;`, alternatively uses images instead of text